# I don't want to manually turn on my wireless everytime computer starts up

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, startup, asus

[image]

How can I have this switched to ON automatically when I log in?

When I startup my machine, that thing is switched OFF and I have to manually switch it ON before I can use the internet.  I can't see any setting in there to have it already turned ON when computer starts up, the box for Connect Automatically is checked but that seems more to be about connecting to known wifi points automatically when wifi is on, rather than turning on wifi automatically.

Ubuntu 11.10 on a Asus Zenbook UX31E.

Comment: Before I can help you find out how to keep that always on at boot, I need your help finding out why your menus look different from my menus.  These are my menus, and I'm on 11.10.    https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/108554992535965401944/albums/5670509808447429889/5725121034845569282?hl=en Are you sure your using Unity on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: I am using gnome-shell , not unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this issue, but it has vanished after upgrading to 12.04.